# Insert Rows Based upon cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have a code to start with this, but I have a worksheet titled "Entry."  In this worksheet, I have several rows of data that begin at row 14.  In cell (E14), I would like a macro that loops through all of the rows beginning with E14, checking for the word STAT.  If the any of the cells beginning with E14 contain Stat, I would like Excel to insert two rows below it and copy the row to the two new rows where STAT was found.  Can this be done in Excel VBA?  I've tried using this partial code but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
Public Sub sortICs()

    Dim bottom As Long, top As Long
    Dim rw As Range, newRow As Range, x, i As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1  'work backwards so you don't interfere when inserting rows
            Set rw = .Rows(i)
            If rw.Columns("C").Value = "STAT" Then
                rw.Offset(1, 0).Insert
                Set newRow = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'the just-inserted row
                rw.Copy newRow
```

Comment: yes, it can be done in Excel VBA. Your "partial code" is missing a few lines before it can even be executed, let alone do what you want it to do, so no suprise it doesn't work

Comment: Also, I would loop from the bottom up. FYI, there are quite a few questions on this site about looping through rows and deleting/adding rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is a good start, but there might be a few issues:

1. You're checking the value in column "C" (`rw.Columns("C").Value`), but you mentioned you want to check column "E".
2. You're only inserting one row, but you mentioned you want to insert two rows.
3. You're starting the loop from the last row of the used range, but you mentioned you want to start from row 14.

Here's a revised version of your code that should accomplish what you're looking for:

```vb
Public Sub sortICs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entry")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column E
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop from the last row to row 14
    For i = lastRow To 14 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(i, "E").Value = "STAT" Then
            ' Insert two rows below
            ws.Rows(i + 1).Resize(2).Insert
            ' Copy the current row to the two new rows
            ws.Rows(i).Copy ws.Rows(i + 1).Resize(2)
            ' Reverse the sign of the values in column B for the two new rows
            ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = -ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
            ws.Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = -ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

This code will loop through all rows starting from E14, and if it finds the word "STAT" in column E, it will insert two rows below and copy the current row to the two new rows. Try this and let us know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks Joaquin.  This works just fine.  Can I ask for a couple of more things.  If I have an amount in column B when the rows are inserted, how do I make the amounts the opposite value from the row that was copied.

Comment: Thanks Joaquin.  This code works just fine.  I will go ahead and flag it shortly.  Can I ask for a couple more things?
If a cell has an amount in it and contains Stat, can I add in an opposite amounts below the row copied?

E.g. see below:

Amount 
100
-100
100

Comment: I've edited and updated the code Fred